# ImportError: cannot import name signals (haystack)

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Setting up the haystack module and Whoosh with all settings. When you try to `./manage.py rebuild_index` 
I get

```
Unknown command: 'rebuild_index'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

From the shell:

```
    import haystack
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:50: RuntimeWarning: SQLite received a naive datetime (2014-01-30 05:17:29.945926) while time zone support is active.
      RuntimeWarning)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImproperlyConfigured                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
    ----> 1 import haystack

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py in <module>()
         32 # Check the 2.X+ bits.
         33 if not hasattr(settings, 'HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS'):
    ---> 34     raise ImproperlyConfigured('The HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS setting is required.')
         35 if DEFAULT_ALIAS not in settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS:
         36     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The default alias '%s' must be included in the HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS setting." % DEFAULT_ALIAS)

    ImproperlyConfigured: The HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS setting is required.
import haystack
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: import haystack
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 import haystack

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
      5 from haystack.constants import DEFAULT_ALIAS
----> 6 from haystack import signals
      7 from haystack.utils import loading
      8 

ImportError: cannot import name signals

Comment: Well, it is hard to guess anything else than what the traceback points out : a misconfiguration of the "HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS" -required- setting. Can you add the relevant part of your settings.py ?

Comment: `WHOOSH_INDEX = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIRECTORY,'whoosh/')
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'whoosh_index'),
        },
    }`

Comment: Please use [edit] to move your additional information from the comments into the question itself.